# Current row value on listpage init() method Dynamics AX

Tags: forms, axapta, record

I would like to get current clicked record value on AssetTableListPage. I need value AssetTable.AssetGroup from active record in listpage in init() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clicked record from the list page is available in the called form through the [element.args()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/args.aspx).record().

In the called form:

```
void init()
{
     AssetTable assetTable = element.args().record();
     // Use assetTable from AssetTableListPage
     super();
}
```

Comment: I get null infolog assetTable = element.args().record();
    super(); info(assetTable.AssetGroup);

Comment: In the Listpage mark the menu item properties with the correct datasource. Also, show the AssetGroup field in the listpage, else it may not be fetched.

Comment: I think that it is not visible, because on this listpage are join two datasources. It can be problem

Comment: No, if RecId is available it should be easy to find with `AssetTable::findByRecId(element.args().record().RecId)`

Comment: I put `info(strFmt("%1",AssetTable.AssetGroup));` in active() method in datasource and it is still null

Comment: What about `AssetTable.RecId`?

Comment: Infolog display 0. But record exist in table AssetTable it's strange...

Comment: Okay, you do not get a record. Did you verify that the menu item has a datasource in the property?

Comment: There isn't property datasource in this Menu Item Display

Comment: There is on the menu item control in the list page.